# How to count clicks with mouselistener and timer

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, actionlistener, mouselistener

So I am having a bit of trouble writing a mouse listener because I want the action to be performed only on a double click. I am trying to use a timer to reset a value that keeps track of the clicks but I don't think I have the correct understanding of the timers.

```
 getTable().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
          if ( isClickedOnce && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
          {
              isClickedOnce = false;
              System.out.println("anything");
          }
          else if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e))
          {
              isClickedOnce = true;
              Timer time = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                            {isClickedOnce=false;}
              });
              time.start();
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java will do this for you. Within mouseClicked():

```
if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I want it to happen for only back to back clicks, not one click and another click 30  seconds later.

Comment: @Rich did you test out this code? Because that's not how getClickCount() behaves. This only happen on a double click.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I did not realize this. I saw other posts that said otherwise but you are correct it works.